# How do I earn the "Passed Judgement" and "Reanimated" hats?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, winter-bash-2013

The description for the "Passed Judgement" hat says:

> participate in closing or deleting a question

(the description for "Reanimated" is similar)

Is that only for close votes, or does it include flagging to close? What about closing my own questions? Does the the question actually have to be closed for my close-vote to give me the hat?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It applies to both flags ([as pointed out by PeterJ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212263/how-do-i-earn-the-passed-judgement-and-reanimated-hats/212264?noredirect=1#comment682968_212264)) and close-votes, and the question does actually have to be closed for you to earn the hat. The same applies to "Reanimated" and reopen votes.

After a quick experiment, I have determined that deleting your own question does not give you the hat.

Comment: It applied to flags as well. For example I have one here and only have a rep of 297.