# How do I earn the Winter Bash 2013 non-secret hats?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2013

*This is intended to be the non-secret counterpart to* [How Do I Get the Winterbash 2013 Secret Hats?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212799/how-do-i-get-the-winterbash-2013-secret-hats)

Some of the descriptions of how to earn a hat on the [Winter Bash 2013](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/) page are confusing or incomplete.

How *exactly* can I earn these hats?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Feel free to edit this to add more hats!

---

### [image: R-E-S-P-E-C-T] R-E-S-P-E-C-T

[*hit the daily reputation cap*](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/respect)

Earn 200 reputation on a single site, within one day (as defined by UTC Time).

---

### [image] Sock Puppet

[*ask and answer your own question, each with a score of 1 or more*](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/sock-puppet)

---

### [image] Do the Swim!

[*review 5 items*](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/do-the-swim)

Complete 5 or more [reviews](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review) of any type.

---

### [image] Lonesome Cowboy

[*earn the tumbleweed badge*](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/lonesome-cowboy)

Earn the ["Tumbleweed" badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/tumbleweed), which states:

> [Ask] a question with no votes, no answers, no comments, and low views for a week.

---

### [image] The Milliner

[*earn 20 hats*](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/the-milliner)

From [Michael Hampton's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211986/238586):

> You need to earn 20 hats, after the start of Winter Bash, *on a single site*. You then earn The Milliner hat on that site. (Which means you could earn it more than once...)
>
> This is the same [way the Johnny Three-hats hat works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211713/189912).

---

### [image] Marauder

[*steal an accepted answer checkmark by posting a better answer*](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/marauder)

Post an answer on a question that already has an accepted answer, and have the poster of the question accept your answer over the previously accepted answer.

---

### [image] Passed Judgement

[*participate in closing or deleting a question*](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/passed-judgement)

Adapted from [How do I earn the "Passed Judgement" and "Reanimated" hats?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212263/how-do-i-earn-the-passed-judgement-and-reanimated-hats/212264#212264)

> [You can earn this hat from] flags ([as pointed out by PeterJ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212263/how-do-i-earn-the-passed-judgement-and-reanimated-hats/212264#comment682968_212264)) and close-votes, and the question does actually have to be closed for you to earn the hat. The same applies to "Reanimated" and reopen votes...deleting your own question does not give you the hat.

---

### [image] Reanimated

[*participate in reopening or undeleting a question*](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/reanimated)

Adapted (heavily) from [How do I earn the "Passed Judgement" and "Reanimated" hats?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212263/how-do-i-earn-the-passed-judgement-and-reanimated-hats/212264#212264)

> Vote to undelete or reopen a question. The question does actually have to be reopened or undeleted for you to earn the hat. Undeleting or reopening your own question does not give you the hat.

---

### [image] Old Hat

[*have a user account created in the first month of the site's existence*](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/old-hat)

According to [balpha'a answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212312/238586) on [How do I earn the Old Hat hat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212246/how-do-i-earn-the-old-hat-hat):

> *the user's creation date (hover over the "member for" value on the use profile for the precise time) is before the time when the site's Community user (user id -1) turned 31 days.*

Anna Lear [says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212254/238586):

> ...private beta sites launched during Winterbash will be excluded from the event and you can't earn any hats on them.

---

### [Archaeologist Hat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212115/incorrect-description-of-archaeologist-hat)

---

## All known secret hats:

[How Do I Get the Winterbash 2013 Secret Hats?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212799/how-do-i-get-the-winterbash-2013-secret-hats)

Comment: With everyone being so concerned about gaming the system, I'm curious why a hat that's so ridiculously easy to game (The Marauder) was created?  All you need is a sock puppet or a cohort on SO and that hat is yours.  Now, before anyone starts in with, "Well, who cares?", it's obvious that people **do** care about gaming the system.  I, myself, have made a few suggestions in the past 2 months that were heavily downvoted because "they're too easy to game".

Comment: @JohnnyBones I completely agree.

Comment: I see you don't have a Marauder.  I'll swap one of my answers if you'll swap one of yours.  ;o)

Comment: @JohnnyBones ok shur tats a gr8 idia we shud rily do dat rite nao cuz i liek hat lez do it wich anser does u wunt me 2 swap acepts on

Comment: No!  You were supposed to ask in your Pirate voice!  Forget it...

Comment: @JohnnyBones But I'm not a pirate, I'm some idiot who wants to game a hat.