# Marauder hat not awarded

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2013

A few hours ago I got my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20698308/809009) from 20th of December accepted as an answer and I'm pretty sure that another answer with a higher score was accepted before for one or two days because I always check beck to my answers to find out if it was accepted or if another got accepted instead.

I thought that this qualifies me to earn the **Marauder** hat.

[image]

> steal an accepted answer check mark by posting a better answer

I guess I was wrong. Now it seems that this does not count even if it was posted during the Winter Bash. Can someone confirm that to get this hat it's actually required to post an answer after another was accepted? That it's not enough that OP just decided to change his/her mind and go for another before posted answer?

I'm not native English and the description of the hat makes me think that I deserve one.

Comment: I got that hat, but had to wait a day or 2 for it to register - probably in case OP changes his/her mind again.

Comment: @Bohemian Is that so? Interesting. You could post it as an answer if you provide some evidence. It contradics Aziz's answer.

Comment: I didn't record the timestamp of receiving the hat - it there a way to show it?

Comment: @Bohemian I checked your answers and it seems more likely you got it for this answer http://stackoverflow.com//posts/20706127/timeline where you answered after an answer was accepted.

Comment: yes - it was for that question, but I didn't see the hat for some time after the accept.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Description of the hat could be a bit off. From the post history it looks like that you didn't steal the check mark by posting a better answer. You posted an answer before the OP accepted 1 answer (out of the many answers available including yours). Later OP changed his/her mind and accepted your answer.

**If you would have posted an answer after OP's acceptance which would have changed OP's mind to accept your answer instead, I believe you would have received that hat**.

To provide better clarity for other users, let me try to explain using a scenario. Lets say 2 users posted 1 answer each on a question. OP accepts one answer, later unaccepts that answer, and accepts the second answer. Even though the checkmark moved from one answer to the other but the hat will not be awarded. Now consider that a 3rd answer was posted while the question already had 1 accepted answer. If OP unaccepts earlier answer and accepts the 3rd answer, now the hat will be awarded.

Comment: I guess you are right here: from http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213082/how-do-i-earn-the-winter-bash-2013-non-secret-hats/213083#213083 Post an answer on a question that **already has an accepted answer**, and have the poster of the question accept your answer over the previously accepted answer.

Comment: He says that an answer was accepted before his post.

Comment: @Jeremy OP wrote "another answer with a higher score was accepted". It is not mentioned in the question that "an answer was accepted before he posted his answer". Both are slightly different statements.

Comment: Keep reading in 5 more words: "I'm pretty sure that another answer with a higher score was accepted *before for one or two days*"

Comment: @Jeremy "before for one or two days" meant that a couple of days back another post was the accepted answer but now mine is the accepted answer.

Comment: But then I'm confused about your post. How did he *not* steal the accepted checkmark?

Comment: @Jeremy let me try to explain. Lets say 2 users posted 1 answer each to a question. OP accepted one answer, later unaccepted that answer, and accepted the second answer. Even though the checkmark moved from one answer to the other but hat will not be awarded. Now consider that a 3rd answer was posted while the question already has 1 accepted answer. If OP unaccepts earlier answer and accepts the 3rd answer, now hat will be awarded.

Comment: I see. You have to post and get the check?